# Storage not building the right file url in test?

Tags: laravel, testing, url, storage

I'm writing tests for my application and struggling to understand whi `Storage` class is not building the expected file url.

I'm having thist test that fails on asserting that expected url equals the builded one, so i put an `if` in my code and `dd()` stuff out to understand, and that's the result:

#### IF in my test

```php
if('http://testurl/storage/path/to/file.test' != 
    Storage::disk('default_disk')->url('path/to/file.test')){
        dd(
            config('filesystems.disks.default_disk'),
            Storage::disk('default_disk')->url('path/to/file.test'),
        );
    }
```

#### Output

```
> php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
PHPUnit 9.5.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.4.3
Configuration: C:\Users\silvi\Desktop\RawFile\phpunit.xml

array:3 [
  "driver" => "local"
  "root" => "root/"
  "url" => "http://testurl/storage"
]
"/storage/path/to/file.test"
Script php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit handling the test event returned with error code 1
```

#### Considerations

So in my test the disk configuration is OK, but the `Storage` class build the wrong url like it is ignoring the `url` config section.

Don't think this matters, but (obviously) the storage is fake, made with `Storage::fake('default_disk');` in the `setUp()` method.

#### Laravel

I'm writing tests for a Laravel package, and used `"orchestra/testbench": "^6.2"` as dev dependancy, so according to their [docs](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench/tree/v6.2.0#usage) it brings up a Laravel 6 application skeleton.

### Update

I tried removing the `Storage::fake('default_disk');` and the test passed, having the `Storage` correctly using my configs.
As gbalduzzi said, if the storage is fake it ignores whatever is in my configs.

Comment: Well, if the disk is `fake` it doesn't consider what you have in your `config/filesystems.php` file. It creates a different, fake, disk

Comment: @gbalduzzi yeah, i just tried removing the `Storage::fake('default_disk');` and the test "passed", taking correctly my configs.

Comment: The fact is, you should not be testing that laravel internal facades are correct :)

Comment: @gbalduzzi if you re-write your comment as an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `fake()` to create a disk, Laravel will not consider anymore your configuration from the usual file `config/filesystems.php`.

It will create a custom, fake, disk.

To solve your problem, you should use the actual disk without creating it using `fake()`. This is not ideal though, because running your tests will actually add files into the selected storage.

The fact is, you should not be testing that the Storage facades builds the proper url. Your tests should focus on the code written by YOU. It is laravel job to properly test their interfaces/methods/facades.